# Git clone web application with java backend

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

i am trying to git clone in Intellij IDEA

```
https://github.com/copperhead/AttestationServer
```

The application consist of frontend HTML and javascript along with backend JAVA and sqlite i believe.

> **final HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080), 0);**
>
> https://github.com/copperhead/AttestationServer/blob/master/src/main/java/co/copperhead/attestationserver/AttestationServer.java#L203

How do i run

> public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

How do i solve this? Or is am missing something? How do I get a local copy that is 100% working as the Actual working online implementation.

**Actual working online implementation:**

> https://attestation.copperhead.co/

Comment: Please describe the actual behaviour you are having right now. Are any exceptions thrown?

Comment: i am new to intellij. how do i even proceed to run public static void?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html

Comment: i cant right click the class and press run. The choice is not available.

Comment: why is my java class icon is spelt as "J" instead of "C" for class?

Comment: I wont answer any further questions regarding IntelliJ basics, they are well documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/) and should not be hard to lookup with a bit of effort.